# Android custom radio button

Tags: android, styles, radio-button, customization, shapes

I need to customize a radio button but I'm having terrible difficulties.I need to do it in a way without creating new images (if possible).

I was looking at defining shapes instead of png but I can't get it to work. Can someone show me how to create and apply shapes and styles?

Here is how I need them to look like:

[image]

I dont think it should be very difficult but I couldn't find a tutorial explaining how shapes work.

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163628/adding-custom-radio-buttons-in-android

Comment: Try this solution 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352259/android-ring-shape-for-radio-button/31432072#31432072

Answer (score 2):

Use this link select radio style...!

http://android-holo-colors.com/

Save all drawable files,images,style and theme in your project..

Comment: is it possible to create a shape and give it the look I want? because this website doesn't give me exactly what I need.

Comment: I'm not getting exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

RadioButton can be customized by customizing application themes or radio button material theme as shown below to change colors of radio button. For other customizations see http://www.zoftino.com/android-ui-control-radiobutton

```
<style name="MyRaidoButtonTwo" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">#64dd17</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#460745</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">#c51162</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryDisableOnly">#00838f</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat</item>
</style>
```

[image]