# How to programmatically change in PopupMenu the radiobutton color

Tags: android

How to programmatically change the `radiobutton` color which is inside the `popupmenu`

```
private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getContext(), view);
    popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_publish_more_popup, popupMenu.getMenu());
    MenuItem postItem = popupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_post);
    postItem.setChecked(true);
    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) (postItem.getActionView());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{
                        new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, //disabled
                        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled} //enabled
                },
                new int[]{
                        Color.GREEN
                        , Color.RED
                }
        );
        radioButton.setButtonTintList(colorStateList);//set the color tint list
        radioButton.invalidate(); //could not be necessary
    }
    popupMenu.show();
}
```

[xml code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYW0e.png)
[radio button is in redbox of picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpzE6.png)

Comment: Please explain clearly and post what u have done

Comment: You might be looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120199/change-circle-color-of-radio-button-android

Comment: you need to set custom theme for popup.

Comment: But the question now is how to get the radiobutton inside PopupMenu.

Answer (score 0):

Define colorstatelist first

```
ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{
                        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled} //enabled
                },
                new int[] {getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary) }
        );
```

then assign them

```
AppCompatRadioButton radioButton = (AppCompatRadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb);
radioButton.setSupportButtonTintList(colorStateList);

AppCompatCheckBox cbSelected = (AppCompatCheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbSelected);
cbSelected.setSupportButtonTintList(colorStateList);
```

or else if this doesn't work then use this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    male.setButtonTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(ReservationContact.this, R.color.background)));
}
male.setHighlightColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.background));
```

Comment: But now that radiobutton is inside PopupMenu, how should I change its color?

Comment: Can u show the code snippet .. Check this video -----> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIqYBTvF6jQ

Comment: I watched the video, but there's no in the video to programmatically set the radiobutton color in PopupMenu.

Comment: On top of that getactionview is null for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, view);
        popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_publish_more_popup, popupMenu.getMenu());
         popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {  
                     public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {  
                      if(item.getTitle().equals("Create Post")){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21)
    {

        ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{

                        new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, //disabled
                        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled} //enabled
                },
                new int[] {

                        Color.WHITE//disabled
                        ,Color.RED//enabled

                }
            );                       


        radio.setButtonTintList(colorStateList);//set the color tint list
        radio.invalidate(); //could not be necessary
    }
    } 
                      return true;  
                     }  
                    });  

                    popup.show();//showing popup menu
```

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioButton

Comment: ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
    new int[][]{new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled} //enabled
    },
    new int[] {getResources().getColor(R.color.red) }
    );

        RadioButton button = (RadioButton) popupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_post);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    button.setButtonTintList(colorStateList);
    }

Comment: Hi, how to get RadioButton?

Comment: Hi , in onMenuItemClick just add this line to check if the button contains the same title of your radioButton : if(item.getTitle() == "Create Post")

Comment: 【RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) popupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_post);】I use this code, but radioButton == null.

Comment: "Hi , in onMenuItemClick just add this line to check if the button contains the same title of your radioButton : if(item.getTitle() == "Create Post")"
-Yes, use equals is right.

Comment: If use "==" result is false, if use "equal" result is true.

Comment: Yes, but now how can I get to radiobutton?

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
MenuItem menuitem=popupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_post);
RadioButton radioButton=  (RadioButton)(MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuitem));//menuitem.getActionView();
radioButton.setButtonTintList(colorstateList);
```

And in your menu, add the `actionViewClass`,

```
<item
android:id="@+id/action_post"
android:actionViewClass="android.widget.RadioButton"
/>
```

Your `colorStateList` should be like,

```
 ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{
                    new int[]{}, //otherwise for all cases
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked} //checked
            },
            new int[]{
                    Color.GREEN,Color.RED
            }
    );
```

Comment: ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{
                        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled} //enabled
                },
                new int[]{getResources().getColor(R.color.red)}
        );
  
     MenuItem menuitem = popupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_post);
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) (menuitem.getActionView());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            radioButton.setButtonTintList(colorStateList);
        }

Comment: Using the code above will be error：java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioButton.setButtonTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)' on a null object reference

Comment: Get the RadioButton is null.

Comment: An error occurred, I debug to find radioButton = null

Comment: @裴佳瑞   could you please post your popup menu creation code. If you have used setactionview() then getactionview() will work fine..I think, it is  better to choose popup window than menu

Comment: mMaterialButtonGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPopupMenu(mMaterialButtonGo);
            }
        });
    }

    private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getContext(), view);
        popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_publish_more_popup, popupMenu.getMenu());
        popupMenu.show();

        MenuItem postItem = popupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_post);
        postItem.setChecked(true);
    }

Comment: Add `actionviewclass` in your menu as `android.widget.RadioButton` .Then try getactionview() method

Comment: **Now 'RadioButton' can be get**, but I tested setting the color answer above, but the color of 'RadioButton' has not been changed, how should I change the color of 'RadioButton'?

Comment: You have to create custom drawables and use it as `radioButton.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable);` if your min api is <21.

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352259/android-ring-shape-for-radio-button)

Comment: This is to change the color in the form of xml, but now the application allows the user to pass in the color code to set the theme, so I have to programmatically change the color

Comment: Yes, my android version is greater than 21, the code is called, but the color does not work

Comment: What should I do to programmatically change the color of 'RadioButton'?

Comment: ColorStateList will work fine. Please check your code or else edit your question with complete code

Comment: instead of using states as enable/disable, try checked

Comment: No, now `radiobutton` the color will not be changed, what am I doing wrong? How should I change is correct?